# Using Cloudformation to Deploy Lamba, Including a Parameter that the function will have access to

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation

We have an API that will be used to provision certain resources in AWS using Cloud Formation. This includes a Lambda function that will send events to S3, with the bucket being configurable. The thing is, we will know the bucket name when we provision the lambda, not within the lambda code itself.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to inject the S3 bucket name at the time of provisioning, in the Cloud Formation Template itself. Is that true?

The only solution I can see is to generate the function code on the fly, and embed that into the Cloud Formation template. This would make us unable to use any NPM dependencies along with the function code. Is there a better option?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `Lambda function that will send events to S3`. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I realized I had never updated this question with my eventual solution. I ended up embedding a proxy lambda function into the cloudformation template, which enabled me to inject template parameters.

Example:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "Creates a function to relay messages from a Kinesis instance to S3",
"Parameters": {
    "S3Bucket" : {
        "Type": "String",
        "Description": "The name of the S3 bucket where the data will be stored"
    },
    "S3Key": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Description": "The key of the directory where the data will be stored"
    }
},

"Resources": {
    "mainLambda": {
        "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties" : {
            "Handler" : "index.handler",
            "Description" : "Writes events to S3",
            "Role" : { "Ref": "LambdaRoleARN" },
            "Runtime" : "nodejs4.3",
            "Code" : {
                "S3Bucket": "streams-resources",
                "S3Key": "astro-bass/${GIT_COMMIT}/lambda/astro-bass.zip"
            }
        }
    },

    "lambdaProxy": {
        "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties" : {
            "Handler" : "index.handler",
            "Runtime" : "nodejs",
            "Code" : {
                "ZipFile": { "Fn::Join": ["", [
                    "var AWS = require('aws-sdk');",
                    "var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();",
                    "exports.handler = function(event, context) {",
                        "event.bundledParams = ['",
                            { "Ref": "S3Bucket" },
                            "','",
                            { "Ref": "S3Key" },
                        "'];",
                        "lambda.invoke({",
                            "FunctionName: '",
                            { "Ref": "mainLambda" },
                            "',",
                            "Payload: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2),",
                            "InvocationType: 'Event'",
                        "}, function(err, data) {",
                            "if(err) {",
                                "context.fail(err);",
                            "}",
                            "context.done();",
                        "});",
                    "};"
                ]]}
            }
        }
    },
},

...
}
```

The proxy function had the parameters injected into its code (s3bucket/key), and then it invokes the main lambda with a modified event object. It's a little unorthodox but struck me as much cleaner than the other available solutions, such as parse stacknames/etc. Worked well thus far.

Note that this solution only works currently with the legacy node environment. Not an issue, but worrisome in terms of the longevity of this solution.

**UPDATE:** 
We ran into limitations with the previous solution and had to devise yet another one. We ended up with an off-label usage of the description field to embed configuration values. Here is our Lambda

```
'use strict';
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({apiVersion: '2014-11-11'});

let promise = lambda.getFunctionConfiguration({ FunctionName: process.env['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME'] }).promise();

exports.handler = async function getTheConfig(event, context, cb) {
    try {
        let data = await promise;
        cb(null, JSON.parse(data.Description).bucket);
    } catch(e) {
        cb(e);
    }
};
```

Then, in the description field, you can embed a simple JSON snipped like so:

```
{
    "bucket": "bucket-name"
}
```

Moreover, this structure, using the promise outside of the handler, limits the request to only occurring when the container is spawned - not for each individual lambda execution.

Not quite the cleanest solution, but the most functional one we've found.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of passing parameters to a Lambda function beside the event itself at the moment.

If you are creating a Lambda function with CloudFormation you could use the following workaround:

- Use the Lambda function name to derive the CloudFormation stack name.
- Use the CloudFormation stack name to access resources, or parameters of the stack when executing the Lambda function.

Comment: I don't really trust deriving the stack name from the function name itself, but interesting idea none-the-less. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it like this.

First create an index.js file and add this code.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const options = {
        hostname: process.env.ApiUrl,
        port: 443,
        path: '/todos',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers:', res.headers);

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
    });
    req.end();


};
```

Zip the index.js file and upload it to an S3 bucket in the same region as your lambda function.

Then use this Cloudformation template make sure you specific the correct bucket name.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "ApiWorkflow",
    "Metadata": {

    },
    "Parameters": {
        "ApiUrl": {
            "Description": "Specify the api url",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
        },
    },
    "Mappings": {

    },
    "Conditions": {

    },
    "Resources": {
        "lambdaVodFunction": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket": "lamdba-exec-tests",
                    "S3Key": "index.js.zip"
                },
                "Handler": "index.handler",
                "Role": "arn:aws:iam::000000000:role/BasicLambdaExecRole",
                "Runtime": "nodejs10.x",
                "FunctionName": "ApiWorkflow",
                "MemorySize": 128,
                "Timeout": 5,
                "Description": "Texting Lambda",
                "Environment": {
                    "Variables": {
                        "ApiUrl": {
                            "Ref": "ApiUrl"
                        },
                        "Test2": "Hello World"
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "ApiUrl": {
            "Description": "Set api url",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "ApiUrl"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should see in the template Environmental variables you can access these in your NodeJS Lambda function like this.

```
process.env.ApiUrl
```